# how to call jquery in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress-theming

I'm a newbie here. please help me on my problem.

I already enqueue script in my wp function and add      inside my header.php file, However I still can't use jquery on my website.. what should i do next?

Comment: Welcome SO please visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery` is integrated by default in the newest version of wordpress. You don't have to enqueue it again. If you want to see if it's there, write in your browser console `jQuery` and see if there will be some response. Also you have to know that, if you make a custom jquery logic there will be some conflicts with `$` in wordpress and jquery

Comment: if i don't need to enqueue it how can i call it?

Comment: Can you give me more information about what you are trying to achieve. For example if you want to make some logic when the DOM is ready you have to wrap your logic in $(document).ready(function(){//your code goes here});

Answer (score 0):

Procedure for add jquery in your wordpress theme

you need to place js file in theme js folder:
ex:myscript.js

```
jQuery("#custom-header").css('border','2px solid red');
```

Procedure for calling myscript.js

follow code you nedd to place theme function.php

```
    function js_head_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script( "headerjs",  get_template_directory_uri()."/js/myscript.js" );
    }

add_action('wp_head', 'js_head_scripts');
```